# Swing size issue for different screen resolution

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm using Java Swing and I want to it to set its `JFrame` size and the size of inner components size based on Screen resolution. I also want it to be compatible on any device like Tablet, laptop. Any easy solution for this?

Comment: This is why [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) where created.  You can also set the frames extended state to `MAXIMIZED_BOTH`, [Frame#setExtendedState](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29), or if you're really adventurous, you can even try [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/)

Comment: *"Any easy solution for this?"*  That depends.  Do you think layouts are easy?  To expand on what was said by @MadProgrammer I'll add a common comment.. Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.

Answer (score 3):

> I also want it to be compatible on any device like Tablet,laptop.Any
>   easy solution for this.

- Put `JScrollPane` to `JFrame`, then put `JPanel` nested all `JComponent`s to `JScrollPane`, then all `JComponent`s are accesible for non-standard screens e.g net_books, crazy tablets with two or more Native OS (most of screen in Native OS there is scrolled by default)

> I'm using **Java Swing** and I want to it to set its **JFrame** size and the
>   size of inner components size based on Screen resolution.

- This is a job for LayoutManager

---

- for really better look is not possible without manage with Font size, basically there are a few screen ratios (4:3, 16:9 ...) with a corresponding pixels (screen) resolutions, rest of then to leave for JScrollPane
- there is not universal advice, everything depends of your GUI, how JComponents are laid, number of JComponents, its Rectangle on the screen
- about the arts, make it look nice and good concept, (then nothing complicated)